# Kedro-mlflow usage - when to use it from notebooks, and when from kedro pipeline?

Tags: mlflow, kedro

I'm a bit confused - what is the common practice for kedro-mlflow usage? It's seems slightly uncomfortable to use it only from kedro pipelines, but kedro intention is fully reproducible research.

At the same time rather rare tutorials on kedro-mlflow usage describe experiments creation from Jupiter notebooks, which seems natural, but then full reproducibility without the full pipeline is broken.

Question - what are common patterns on kedro-mlflow usage, as well as subexperiments creation (in scope of CrossValidation or HyperOptimisation)? When kedro pipelines should be used, and when code (and which code) should be placed in notebooks?

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/Galileo-Galilei/kedro-mlflow? Might be worth opening an issue there instead, likelier to get a response than on here, I suspect!

Comment: Yes, that's the plugin for kedro. The do have some examples but no guidelines relating best practices.